# Emulating multiple dispatch in S3 (for 3 signature arguments)

Tags: r, oop, dispatch, multidispatch

I'm aware of the general [ins and outs](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) of the different OO systems in R and I'm all for staying in S3 whenever/as long as I can.

However, the need for [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) keeps haunting me in professional projects and kept pulling me into S4 in the past.

But I refuse to accept that I can't find a S3 **emulation** of multi dispatch à la S4 that is at least able to support my primary use case of avoiding unsystematic [data drift](https://streamsets.com/resources/analyst-reports/data-drift/):

1. My analytical programs create data structures that I publish to stakeholders for them to consume as part of some data pipelines
2. Usually I publish to a DBMS such as MongoDB, thus my structures somewhat manifest themselves and could/should be thought of as DB schemas
3. I follow a "release early, release often" approach to stay agile, so It's natural that "things change" - often and over time
4. As data structures eventually evolve, I want to be explicit about describing the structure so I can define internal migration routines and/or make stakeholders aware of which version of data structures they are dealing with in the DB

If I go about describing my data structures via some versioning scheme (which is the best I could think of so far), I basically need to base my methods on **three** signature arguments regarding method dispatch:

1. One for the input (class) of a given data transformation task
2. One for the version of the input (class)
3. One for the version of the output (class)

### Due diligence

Apart from the [OO field guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) I've read:

- [Multiple dispatch for `subset` methods in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346939/multiple-dispatch-for-subset-methods-in-r)
- [Multi dispatch gist by Winston Chang](https://gist.github.com/wch/adf13fd291976d6bf312)

### My approach

Sequential S3-based approach for an `input_class` and an `output_class` that both can evolve over time structure-wise, which is captures by respective version classes such as `v1`, `v2` etc.

#### Step 1: Define necessary base components

```
# Generic that dispatches on `x`
new_output_class <- function(x, schema_version_in, schema_version_out, ...) {
  UseMethod("new_output_class", x)
}

# Generic that dispatches on 'schema_version_in' and 
# can thus be used to define distinct methods for 
# different versions of 'input_class'
new_output_class__input_class <- function(x, schema_version_in, 
  schema_version_out, ...) {
  UseMethod("new_output_class__input_class", schema_version_in)
}

# Generic that dispatches on 'schema_version_out' and 
# can thus be used to define distinct methods for 
# different versions of 'output_class' for inputs of class `input_class`
# with version class `v1`
new_output_class__input_class__v1 <- function(x, schema_version_in, 
  schema_version_out, ...) {
  UseMethod("new_output_class__input_class__v1", schema_version_out)
}

# Top-level method for dispatch based on `input_class`
new_output_class.input_class <- function(
  x, 
  schema_version_in,
  schema_version_out
) {
  message("Level 1: method for `input_class`")

  new_output_class__input_class(x, schema_version_in, schema_version_out)
}
```

#### Step 2: Define methods for the initial case of `input_class = v1` and `output_class = v1`

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

# Method for `input_class` of version `v1`
new_output_class__input_class.v1 <- function(
  x, 
  schema_version_in,
  schema_version_out
) {
  # message("Sub-level 1: `input_class/in:v1`")
  message(stringr::str_glue("Level 2: method for `input_class/in:{schema_version_in}`"))

  new_output_class__input_class__v1(x, schema_version_in, schema_version_out)
}

# Method for `output_class` of version `v1` for inputs 
# of `input_class` of version `v1`
new_output_class__input_class__v1.v1 <- function(
  x, 
  schema_version_in,
  schema_version_out
) {
  message(stringr::str_glue("Level 3: method for `input_class/in:{schema_version_in}/out:{schema_version_out}`"))

  structure(x, 
    class = c(stringr::str_glue("output_class_{schema_version_out}"),
      "output_class")
  )
}

x <- structure(letters[1:3], class = "input_class")

schema_version_of_x <- structure("v1", class = "v1")
schema_version_of_new_output <- structure("v1", class = "v1")

new_output_class(x, schema_version_of_x, schema_version_of_new_output)
# Level 1: method for `input_class`
# Level 2: method for `input_class/in:v1`
# Level 3: method for `input_class/in:v1/out:v1`
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "output_class_v1" "output_class"
```

#### Step 3: Handling evolution of `output_class` to `v2`

```
# Method for `output_class` of version `v2` for inputs 
# of `input_class` of version `v1`
new_output_class__input_class__v1.v2 <- function(
  x,
  schema_version_in,
  schema_version_out
) {
  message(stringr::str_glue("Level 3: method for `input_class/in:{schema_version_in}/out:{schema_version_out}`"))

  structure(x %>% rep(2),
    class = c(stringr::str_glue("output_class_{schema_version_out}"),
      "output_class")
  )
}

schema_version_of_new_output <- structure("v2", class = "v2")
new_output_class(x, schema_version_of_x, schema_version_of_new_output)
# Level 1: method for `input_class`
# Level 2: method for `input_class/in:v1`
# Level 3: method for `input_class/in:v1/out:v2`
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "output_class_v2" "output_class"
```

#### Step 4: Handling evolution of `input_class` to `v2`

```
# Generic for input `input_class` of version `v2`
new_output_class__input_class__v2 <- function(x, schema_version_in, 
  schema_version_out, ...) {
  UseMethod("new_output_class__input_class__v2", schema_version_out)
}

# Method for `input_class` of version `v2`
new_output_class__input_class.v2 <- function(
  x, 
  schema_version_in,
  schema_version_out
) {
  message(stringr::str_glue("Level 2: method for `input_class/in:{schema_version_in}`"))

  new_output_class__input_class__v2(x, schema_version_in, schema_version_out)
}

# Method for `output_class` of version `v1` for inputs 
# of `input_class` of version `v2`
new_output_class__input_class__v2.v1 <- function(
  x, 
  schema_version_in,
  schema_version_out
) {
  message(stringr::str_glue("Level 3: method for `input_class/in:{schema_version_in}/out:{schema_version_out}`"))

  structure(x %>% tolower(),
    class = c(stringr::str_glue("output_class_{schema_version_out}"),
      "output_class")
  )
}

x <- structure(LETTERS[1:3], class = "input_class")
schema_version_of_x <- structure("v2", class = "v2")
schema_version_of_new_output <- structure("v1", class = "v1")
new_output_class(x, schema_version_of_x, schema_version_of_new_output)
# Level 1: method for `input_class`
# Level 2: method for `input_class/in:v2`
# Level 3: method for `input_class/in:v2/out:v1`
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "output_class_v1" "output_class"   

# Method for `output_class` of version `v2` for inputs 
# of `input_class` of version `v2`
new_output_class__input_class__v2.v2 <- function(
  x, 
  schema_version_in,
  schema_version_out
) {
  message(stringr::str_glue("Level 3: method for `input_class/in:{schema_version_in}/out:{schema_version_out}`"))

  structure(x %>% tolower() %>% rep(2),
    class = c(stringr::str_glue("output_class_{schema_version_out}"),
      "output_class")
  )
}

schema_version_of_x <- structure("v2", class = "v2")
schema_version_of_new_output <- structure("v2", class = "v2")
new_output_class(x, schema_version_of_x, schema_version_of_new_output)
# Level 1: method for `input_class`
# Level 2: method for `input_class/in:v2`
# Level 3: method for `input_class/in:v2/out:v2`
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "output_class_v2" "output_class"
```

#### Pros

1. It works
2. It's S3
3. It's systematic

#### Cons

1. It's even more verbose than any S4-based solution
2. I don't like it at all

Did anyone come up with a better emulation of multi dispatch in S3 yet?